# Lodash orderBy object of arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array:

```
const names = [{name: 'a', equal: 3},
{name: 'b', equal: 2},
{name: 'c', equal: 2},
{name: 'd', equal: 3},
{name: 'a1', equal: 1}]
```

I'm running _.groupBy(names, 'equal') and as a result I get:

```
{1: [{equal: 1, name: 'a1'}],
 2: [{equal: 2, name: 'b'}, {equal: 2, name: 'c'}],
 3: [{equal: 3, name: 'a'}, {equal: 3, name: 'd'}]}
```

But here the sorting by name disappears. How do I sort by name in this object?

**Update**

I want to get:

```
{3: [{equal: 3, name: 'a'}, {equal: 3, name: 'd'}],
 1: [{equal: 1, name: 'a1'}],
 2: [{equal: 2, name: 'b'}, {equal: 2, name: 'c'}]}
```

Comment: So you want sorted by equal, then sorted by name for objects with the same equal?

Comment: Yes, I want to get: {3: [{equal: 3, name: 'a'}, {equal: 3, name: 'd'}],
 1: [{equal: 1, name: 'a1'}],
 2: [{equal: 2, name: 'b'}, {equal: 2, name: 'c'}]}

Comment: object have either no order or in upcoming JS, the order is numerical with integer values.

Comment: How to make an array of arrays of objects? [[{name: 'a'}], [{name: 'b'}, {name: c}]]

Comment: why is `1` in the middle and `2` at the the end? how should look like the result array?

Comment: Sorted by name. 3=>'a', 1=>'a1', 2=>'b'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using an array as result set, you could sort it later after grouping.

```js
var names = [{ name: 'a', equal: 3 }, { name: 'b', equal: 2 }, { name: 'c', equal: 2 }, { name: 'd', equal: 3 }, { name: 'a1', equal: 1 }],
    equals = {},
    result = [];

names.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!equals[o.equal]) {
        equals[o.equal] = [];
        result.push(equals[o.equal]);
    }
    equals[o.equal].push(o);
});

result.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[0].name.localeCompare(b[0].name);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use lodash methods groupBy and sortBy together

**DEMO**

```js
const names = [{name: 'a', equal: 3},
{name: 'b', equal: 2},
{name: 'c', equal: 2},
{name: 'd', equal: 3},
{name: 'a1', equal: 1}];

var grouped = _.groupBy(names, function(name) {
  return name.equal;
});
 var result = _.sortBy(grouped, ['name']);
console.log(grouped);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.2/lodash.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: than it differs from _.groupBy(names, 'equal')?

Comment: sorry misunderstood the question

Comment: why do you say so? how do you want the op?

Comment: you need a sorted object by name {3: [{equal: 3, name: 'a'}, {equal: 3, name: 'd'}],
 1: [{equal: 1, name: 'a1'}],
 2: [{equal: 2, name: 'b'}, {equal: 2, name: 'c'}]}

Comment: first 3, then 1, then 2